Liquibase with Gradle - How to generate the current state of the database with the Liquibase using Gradle?
I added the Liquibase to the existing project and would like to generate the current state of the database. But the problem is that the project is using Gradle, and I'm not that familiar with Gradle, I've just worked with Maven so far and also everywhere on the Internet I can just find the tutorial for the Maven.
Does anyone knows how can I generate the current state of the database (postgreSql) with Liquibase and Gradle?
I tried using JPABuddy but it only generated the few change sets, but I need the complete state of the database. I also know that there is a liquibase-hibernate plugin but I don't know how to use it with gradle. And I also tried liquibase-gradle-plugin but the gradle does not recognize it.

@htshame When I try to generate it like this, I get this error:
liquibase : The term 'liquibase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,  verify that the path is correct and try again.
I'm using liquibase core plugin - 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core' and the liquibase is working normally on my project, but the liquibase command is not recognized


Install Liquibase CLI. https://docs.liquibase.com/start/install/home.html  2. Use Liquibase CLI to generate changeLog https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/inspection/generate-changelog.html


Liquibase CLI was the thing that I was missing, I got the generated current state of the DB. Thank you for the help!
